# What can "look north" mean in a sentence?

Tags: meaning

I have a question. It starts with a sentence: Bitcoin Price Looks North After Passing $6.4K Resistance.
What does 'look north' mean in this sentence?

Below is the URL if you wish to read more about the article to understand the word.
https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-indicator-turns-bullish-for-first-time-in-8-months/

Answer (score 2):

It means "Bitcoin's price is predicted to continue going up."

*North* is at the top of (most) maps, and higher values are (generally) at the top of graphs. *Looks xxx* is way of saying "looks like it will move in the direction of xxx."